# SQL query to update to current timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, postico

I am using rails5/postgres. Currently, created_at and updated_at is in UTC, how can I update it to local timezone say Sydney Australia using SQL query. Also, I wanted to run the script in postico.

Comment: Have you some code already? What is creating the filed? You via postgres? An other app of any kind?

Answer (score 0):

`update table_name set created_at = created_at + 10 * interval '1 hour';`
`update table_name set updated_at = updated_at + 10 * interval '1 hour';`

Found the above command will update the table time stamp.